How to automatically filter out models fitted with auto.arima function based on bad residual properties?
I am looking for an easy way to filter out "bad" models fitted by auto.arima function.
These are SARIMA models with different parameters and by a "good" model I mean model with good residual properties - i.e. residuals shouldn't be autocorrelated and should be normal. So far I've been visually checking histograms, ACF and PACF plots of residuals for each model but it is too slow and error-prone with over 30 models. I want to add numerical tests for each model to be able to quickly filter out bad ones.
fit_models <- function(...){
  # 1. run auto.arima and capture output then create table with fitted models params
  # 2. for each model refit and save diagnostic plots to output directory
  # 3. MISSING PART: for each model test autocorrelation and normality of 
  #    residuals numerically and append result ("pass" or "no pass") 
  #    as an extra column in summary df with model params and BIC values
}

I want to add something like this:
# for each model's residuals
shapiro_pass <- (shapiro.test(residuals)$p_value > 0.05)
kol_smir_pass <- (ks.test(residuals)$p_value > 0.05)

# append these to model summary row

but I don't know how to easily test the significance of ACF and PACF values.

The difficulty of automatically working with ACF and PACF values is one of the reason why auto.arima() uses information criteria like AIC, AICc or BIC to select a model. Do you want to look at these?

@StephanKolassa information criteria can be used to select the best one - but what if for example models with 2nd and 3rd lowest BIC are almost as good as the best one? I want to select N top models and then use all of them to simulate the process and see how much results can differ. But I don't know how many top models should I use so my idea is to take all with acceptable properties of residuals.

Burnham & Anderson, Model Selection and Multi-Model Inference (2002), suggest as a rule of thumb that differences of up to 2 in ICs imply little practical differences between models. So one possibility would be to use all models whose ICs are within 2 of the lowest-IC model. (Of course you can't compare models with different orders of integration using ICs, so you would need to do something different here.)
